# PHP 5.5.9 support will end by december

Tags: php

I have websites build in PHP version 5.5.9. I read PHP 5.5 support will end by end of December. I want to know what effect will it have on my websites. Will they stop working ?

Comment: PHP 5.5 went EOL back in 2016, I think you're getting 5.5 mixed up with 5.6. You should be looking at updating your code to work with at the minimum 7.1 (which went EOL at the start of the week)

Comment: I have 5.5.9 and i want to upgrade but due to tight schedule, i want to do it in Jan 2019. So for that i am confirming website will be keep running after PHP 5 EOL.

Answer (score 3):

No, your websites will not stop working. PHP 5.5.9 will continue working the same as the day it has been released. There's no remote kill switch or timer built into it that will self-destruct what is currently working.

What *end-of-support* means is that this version is not longer **supported**. I.e. if you discover any bugs in it, have any questions about it, or if security problems are found with it, there's nobody "at PHP" that will help you with those issues or write any patches/fixes/security updates for it. It will continue working exactly as it is right now and will never ever be changed or improved.

The biggest concern here is with security patches. If an important security issue is identified in a current version of PHP, it's usually fixed within days or hours and you can install security updates for your PHP installation. This won't happen for unsupported versions, and you're either left to try to work around any security problems yourself, or you'll simply remain vulnerable forever.